# how to pass array list data from one dialog fragment to another dialog fragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

After a long search on the internet I couldn't find any solution to meet my requirements.
I have one array list which is passed into the dialog fragment, but my requirement is:
When the user selects the date it calls the web service again and gets another data according to data and passes the same dialog fragment. How can I achieve that ? I have tried with static value but its not clearing the value. My code is:

```
public static class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    String userName;


    public interface UserUserIdListener {
        void updateIdUserName(String userName);


    }
    public static final int FLAG_START_DATE = 0;
    public static final int FLAG_END_DATE = 1;
   public  static  List<Orederlist>reportorderIdList=new ArrayList<>();
   // private   List<Userlist> reportUserList = new ArrayList<>();


    private int flag = 0;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void setFlag(int i) {
        flag = i;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendar1=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        String  reportOrderIds="";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
            textviewFromDate.setText(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
            fromDateReport=textviewFromDate.getText().toString();

            JSONObject pieObject = new JSONObject();
            try
            {
                pieObject.put("fromDate",""+fromDateReport);
                pieObject.put("orderId",""+reportOrderIds);
                pieObject.put("password",""+sPrefs.getString(Constants.PASSWORD,""));
                pieObject.put("toDate",""+toDateReport);
                pieObject.put("user",""+sPrefs.getString(Constants.USER_NAME,""));
                pieObject.put("subUser",""+reportSubUsers);
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();



            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // String TAG = "delivered";
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
            JsonObjectRequest jsOnbjRequest = new
                    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                            Constants.GetSummarizedReports, pieObject,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                                {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    try {
                                        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) response.get("orderlist");
                                        {
                                            if (jsonArray.length()>0)
                                            {
                                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                                    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                    // Integer name = json.optInt();
                                                    String name = json.optString("orderId").toString();
                                                    Orederlist user = new Orederlist(name);
                                                    user.setOrderId(name);
                                                    reportorderIdList.add(user);

                                                }}
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            },

                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            }) {
                        @Override
                        public String getBodyContentType() {
                            return "application/json";
                        }

                    };
            jsOnbjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(500000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            requestQueue.add(jsOnbjRequest);

        } else if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE) {
            textviewToDate.setText(format.format( calendar1.getTime()));
            toDateReport= textviewToDate.getText().toString();
            JSONObject pieObject = new JSONObject();

            try
            {
                pieObject.put("fromDate",""+fromDateReport);
                pieObject.put("orderId",""+reportOrderIds);
                pieObject.put("password",""+sPrefs.getString(Constants.PASSWORD,""));
                pieObject.put("toDate",""+toDateReport);
                pieObject.put("user",""+sPrefs.getString(Constants.USER_NAME,""));
                pieObject.put("subUser",""+reportSubUsers);

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();



            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // String TAG = "delivered";
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
            JsonObjectRequest jsOnbjRequest = new
                    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                            Constants.GetSummarizedReports, pieObject,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                                {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                                    try {
                                        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) response.get("orderlist");
                                        {
                                            if (jsonArray.length()>0)
                                            {
                                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                                    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                    // Integer name = json.optInt();
                                                    String name = json.optString("orderId").toString();
                                                    Orederlist user = new Orederlist(name);
                                                    user.setOrderId(name);
                                                    reportorderIdList.add(user);

                                                }


                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            }) {
                        @Override
                        public String getBodyContentType() {
                            return "application/json";
                        }

                    };
            jsOnbjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(500000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            requestQueue.add(jsOnbjRequest);

        }
    }


}
```

and for dialog fragment pass data is :

```
FragmentManager managerOrderIds = getSupportFragmentManager();
            UserJobIds dialogOrderIds = new UserJobIds();
            dialogOrderIds.setdata(orderIdList,reportorderIdList);//with static array list which is not claer the value
            dialogOrderIds.show(managerOrderIds, "Dialog");
```

Comment: See [communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: i saw its already  but my requirement is i have same array ilst how can i pass with the same from getting array list data to activity and pass it to another dialog fragment

Comment: Use activity as a bridge cause its the parent container for both of fragments

Comment: can you please give me some example?

Comment: please give me some tips on that.

Comment: any help on this?

Comment: Do you have 2 DialogFragment ?

Comment: yes i have two dialog fragment one is date picker and second is job id fragment i just want to when user select data from data picker  and download the data it pass to second dialog fragment.

Comment: even i tried with static array list and i am getting secussfully data but due to static value after come again in acivity the data value is not clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161260/discussion-between-ashish-and-adm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is just create a newInstance of Dialog Fragment assign data to it, then call show().Below is an example.

```
public class D2Fragment extends DialogFragment {
private ArrayList<String> list;
public static D2Fragment getInstanceFor(ArrayList<String> list){
    D2Fragment d2Fragment=new D2Fragment();
    d2Fragment.list=list;
    return d2Fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog, container,
            false);
    getDialog().setTitle("DialogFragment Sample");
    Log.e("size",list.size()+"");// Here is the list 
    // Do something else
    return rootView;
}
```

}

When you show dialog.

```
 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Val1");
    list.add("Val2");
    D2Fragment d2Fragment=D2Fragment.getInstanceFor(list);
    d2Fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog2");
```

**Or** just create a setter for your data.

```
public class D2Fragment extends DialogFragment {
private ArrayList<String> list;
public void setData(ArrayList<String> list){
    this.list=list;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog, container,
            false);
    getDialog().setTitle("DialogFragment Sample");
    Log.e("size",list.size()+"");// Here is the list
    // Do something else
    return rootView;
}
```

}

and to show Dialog.

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Val1");
    list.add("Val2");
    D2Fragment d2Fragment = new D2Fragment();
    d2Fragment.setData(list);
    d2Fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog2");
```

In activity you can always find that particular DialgFragment by tag you assigned at the time of transaction.

```
 Fragment fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog2");
            if(fragment!=null && fragment instanceof D2Fragment){
                ((D2Fragment)fragment).call();// You can call any public method of this dialog fragment here
            }
```

Comment: ADM thanks for that bu i already do the same i just want that how can i get custom array list object to from date picker dialog and pass it another dialog fragment i have already array list object .

Comment: Thats what i just imply above with a String ArrayList just use setData() formate i just added above.

Comment: OK, actually i am confused because my dialog fragment is date picker so that is why.

Comment: date picker is an implementation if AlertDialog Not of Dialog Fragment. So you need to pass that list to Activity(using a callback or if you have date picke in same activity then no need of it) . Then use the above code to pass data to next Dialog Fragment. Thats it .